# Process tasks in async

Tags: flask, asynchronous

I've a situation, I created a flask rest api endpoint which allows users to upload audio files. now my requirement is to register the upload events in a queue and acknowledge the users. on the other hand all the upload events should be processed in async way that will generate transcript of the audio file.

```
event_queue = asyncio.Queue()

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    #store the file in file system
    upload_data = request.file  
    event_queue.put_nowait(upload_data.filename)
    return jsonify({'message': 'Event registered successfully'})
```

and event processor is should be able to pic the events registered.

Thank you,

Yes!! but, I dont have sufficient knowledge to implement this